# Jetbrains Intellij Works but Fleet does not : "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, jetbrains-fleet, jetbrains-hub

Trying to work using the fleet ide that was created by Jetbrains

Followed the tuturial on the jetbrains webiste: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-java-in-fleet.html

I am following the one for JAVA and I going for the Gradle wrapper.

Was able to get everything working in intellij

But as shown in the screen shots provided when I go to run it in Fleet I got the error message:
"is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
[image]

[image]